# setting password for excel file when export from android app

Tags: java, android, excel, apache-poi

I am working on export feature from my application. I have to export my DB data as excel sheet.

I need to set password for my excel file.

I am using ApachePOI library to take db data and add to excel sheet.

The library also supports adding password. I have used the code to do it. But my export file is successful. but if I try to open it, it doesn't prompt me for the password.

Code:

```
 Biff8EncryptionKey.setCurrentUserPassword("password");
HSSFWorkbook hwb = new HSSFWorkbook();
HSSFSheet sheet = hwb.createSheet("new sheet");

HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(count);
HSSFCell cell = row.createCell(0);
cell.setCellValue(nextLine[0]);

FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(outFilePath);
hwb.writeProtectWorkbook(Biff8EncryptionKey.getCurrentUserPassword(), "");
hwb.write(fileOut);
```

I don't know if I am doing something wrong in the password code section.
Kindly let me know how to enable password lock for the excel file. Any help on using the `APachePOI` library would be helpful for me.

Any one help me with some sample code for adding password protection to excel sheet.

Comment: Did you try [reading the Apache POI documentation on encryption and password protection](https://poi.apache.org/encryption.html)? Only that's pretty clear that HSSF only supports decrypting, not encrypting, and you have to use XSSF if you want to create new protected office files...

Comment: @Gagravarr  thanks for your reply. I checked the link. but i couldnt understand the details mentioned.i want to add a password to the created excel file before exporting. If you can share any samples to add password protection, it will help me a lot.

Comment: Go to the page linked, and follow the examples from there! You'll have to switch to XSSF though (for `.xlsx`), as HSSF is decrypt-only as that page explains